# Update query for adding new values to the existing records in a database using textbox in visual c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
updatequery = @"UPDATE EMP_DETAILS SET ADVANCE_SAL = 'ADVANCE_SAL + '" + 
Convert.ToDecimal(txtADV.Text) + "'' WHERE EMP_ID = '" + 
Convert.ToInt64(txtEID.Text) + "')";
```

What is wrong with the above code?
.
.
.
The modified code which has an error [Scalar variable @ADVANCE_SAL not declared] is as follows:

```
            var c = dtimePick.Value.TimeOfDay;
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ADVANCE_SAL", SqlDbType.Decimal);
            param.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtADV.Text);
            command.Parameters.Add(param);


            updatequery = @"UPDATE EMP_DETAILS SET ADVANCE_SAL = ADVANCE_SAL +  @ADVANCE_SAL , LATEST_ADVANCE_DATE = '"+c+"' WHERE ENAME = '"+txtEID.Text+"' ";
```

Comment: What error message you are getting?

Comment: your query should be like : `UPDATE EMP_DETAILS SET ADVANCE_SAL = 'ADVANCE_SAL' +  CAST(txtADV.Text AS DECIMAL(20,2)) + ' WHERE EMP_ID = ' + CAST(txtEID.Text AS bigint) + ')`

Comment: Format Exception was unhandled

Comment: @SandipPatel : It is saying "Incorrect Syntax near '+CAST(txtADV.Text AS DECIMAL(20,2)) + '

Comment: Yes, because i have given query for sql and you write at c#, I think John has given right detailed answer

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @SandipPatel : After trying the code as John said, I can see an error i.e., " @ ADVANCE_SAL scalar variable not declared"

Comment: @Shiva show us your modified code.

Comment: @JohnWoo The modified code is as follows:

var c = dtimePick.Value.TimeOfDay;

                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ ADVANCE_SAL", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                param.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtADV.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

               
                updatequery = @ "UPDATE EMP_DETAILS SET ADVANCE_SAL = ADVANCE_SAL +  @ ADVANCE_SAL , LATEST_ADVANCE_DATE = '"+c+"' WHERE ENAME = '"+txtEID.Text+"' ";

Comment: Extra Space is not there in the original code. While commenting, @ cannot be next to ADVANCE_SALARY as it will be considered as a user. That's why I had to add extra space.

Comment: @Shiva paste your code in the question so it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

The error is that you are enclosing `ADVANCE_SAL` with single quote. To make it cleaner and safer from sql injection, you must parameterized the query,

```
updatequery = @"UPDATE EMP_DETAILS 
                SET ADVANCE_SAL = ADVANCE_SAL + @ADVANCE_SAL
                WHERE EMP_ID = @EMP_ID"


using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updatequery , connection))
    {
        // must do proper error handling
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ADVANCE_SAL", Convert.ToDecimal(txtADV.Text)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("EMP_ID", Convert.ToInt64(txtEID.Text)));
        int results = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.However, in my database, the datatype for EMP_ID is bigint.. Is the type of conversion that we are doing here,i.e., Convert.ToInt64(txtEID.Text)  right?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are adding single quote to the EMP_ID and ADVANCE_SAL they are numeric and don't need ', i think following is what you wanted...

```
updatequery = @"UPDATE EMP_DETAILS SET ADVANCE_SAL = ADVANCE_SAL + " + 
Convert.ToDecimal(txtADV.Text) + " WHERE EMP_ID = " + 
Convert.ToInt64(txtEID.Text) + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your implementation.

1- **SQL injection vulnerability** - Rad more on this [here](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)

2- Your query building is not correct, it should be like following. (Quotes are not correct for `ADVANCE_SAL`)

```
updatequery = @"UPDATE EMP_DETAILS SET ADVANCE_SAL = ADVANCE_SAL + " + 
Convert.ToDecimal(txtADV.Text) + " WHERE EMP_ID = '" + 
Convert.ToInt64(txtEID.Text) + "'";
```

3- If any employee have not opted for advance salary (in that case the `ADVANCE_SAL` value can be null in the table). Your query will update it with `NULL` as `NULL + SomeValue = NULL`

For example

```
SELECT NULL +10.0 AS Total
```

Output

```
Total
-----
NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
updatequery = @"UPDATE EMP_DETAILS SET ADVANCE_SAL = 'ADVANCE_SAL + '" + 
Convert.ToDecimal(txtADV.Text) + "'' WHERE ( EMP_ID = '" + 
Convert.ToInt64(txtEID.Text) + "')";
```